# Greenlet version is too old error even the 0.4.5 is installed. Why?

Tags: python, openstack-swift, greenlets

I get this error,
**Your version of greenlet (0.3.1) is too old (required >= 0.3.2)** 
when I am trying to run ssbench openstack-swift benchmarking tool.

I updated the greenlet to the version 0.4.5 using 
sudo pip install --upgrade greenlet

but it still give this error.
I can see the greenlet.so in the distribution folder which is the latest.

Furthermore, I wrote below to check version,

```
import greenlet  
greenlet_version = getattr(greenlet, '__version__', None)
print(str(greenlet_version))
```

This also returned 0.3.1.

I am confused why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

people need to stop hard coding version numbers... the problem is in \Lib\site-packages\gevent\hub.py where it says this:

```
import greenlet  # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet/
greenlet_version = getattr(greenlet, '__version__', None)
if greenlet_version:
    greenlet_version_info = [int(x) for x in greenlet_version.split('.')]
if not greenlet_version or greenlet_version_info[:3] < [0, 3, 2]:
    raise ImportError('''Your version of greenlet (%s) is too old (required >= 0.3.2)
         You can get a newer version of greenlet from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet/''' % (greenlet_version, ))
```

the error is 'your version of greenlet is not listed in my poorly updated list of recognized versions.'  Just comment out lines 12-14 in your copy of the library... sadness.